# Get value from firebase promise in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

firebase.js

```
import config from "./firebaseConfig";
import app from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firebase-firestore";

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.db = app.firestore();
  }

  getBooks = () =>
    this.db
      .collection("books")
      .get()
      .then(docs => docs.forEach(doc => doc.data()))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

export default new Firebase();
```

BookCardsContainer.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import BookCards from "./BookCards";
import firebase from "../../firebase";

const BookCardsContainer = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBooks(firebase.getBooks());
  }, []);

  console.log(books);

  return <div />;
};

export default BookCardsContainer;
```

Why I have Promise {} in the console instead of actual value if I used `then` on `Promise`? I have actual data when I console.log() in firebase.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetBooks is setting the value of books to a promise.

firebase.getBooks() returns a promise.

so this is why you have in books a promise.

What you should do

```
async function fetchMyAPI() {

  const response = await firebase.getBooks();
  setBooks(response);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMyAPI();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with async data, you have to wait for the promise to resolve before it will work like you are expecting it to. Fetching the books takes a while so there is a delay, untill the books arrive all you have is the promise that books will arrive eventually.

To get this to work you can try:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.getBooks().then(books => setBooks(books))
  }, []);
```